# Different font sizes for integral and fractional parts of a float

Tags: c#, wpf, text, textblock

I'd like to display (e.g. in a TextBlock) the fractional part of a float using a smaller font size like this:

[image]

The float value comes from a binding, so it's not static text.

I'm currently using two Run objects with different font sizes inside a TextBlock -- each of which have a binding to the same float value with converters that return the integral, and the fractional part, respectively. But I don't like that this involves two bindings.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I did not post as an answer as I have not tested but I think you could create the two runs in a single converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one idea of improvement : only one converter, and a converter parameter to get either integral or fractional part. (or no parameter for integral, and 'frac' for fractional).